# gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument

Tags: django, bash, ubuntu, gunicorn

I am trying to make a gunicorn bash executable file to run django server but getting error -  `gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument`.

Its working fine with - `gunicorn bekaim_pre_registration.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001`
but getting error with bash file.

Here is my - `gunicorn_start.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="django_app"                                   # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/bekaim_pre_registration               # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/django_env/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=ubuntu                                         # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                       # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bekaim_pre_registration.settings      # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=bekaim_pre_registration.wsgi              # WSGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/ubuntu/django_env/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file
```

To make this script executable.

```
$ sudo chmod u+x gunicorn_start.bash
```

When I test - `./gunicorn_start.bash`

```
Starting django_app as ubuntu
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
gunicorn: error: argument --error-logfile/--log-file: expected one argument
```

I am following this tutorial  - https://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2017/01/deply-django-with-nginx.html

Anyone can help?

Comment: just give it a path as argument or delete that flag

Comment: @Siyu which path I need to pass in arguments ? could you give me code?

Comment: You can put the log wherever you want. It's just a path to place the generated log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually log-file is not defined in configuration -

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="django_app"                                   # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/home/ubuntu/bekaim_pre_registration               # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/home/ubuntu/django_env/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=ubuntu                                         # the user to run as
GROUP=ubuntu                                        # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                       # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bekaim_pre_registration.settings      # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=bekaim_pre_registration.wsgi              # WSGI module name
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/ubuntu/django_env/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```